# How to use ajax to save variable in url

Tags: php, ajax

I have this Code, which is based in a File named trainerModuleView.php and i need the variable lastDeletedUser in a File named database.php

```
echo '<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "trainerModulview.php?groupID="+$currentGroupID+"&lastDeletedUser="+$id,
        success: function(data) {

        },
    });
</script>';
```

I have a Group with students and if i delete one of them, i would like to have the variable in my URL, so i can $_GET['lastDeletedUser'] it later in the database.php. The problem is though, that the URL doesn't even change.

Pls halp
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can always just end and start your PHP instead of echoing it. Also you can use `<?=$VARIABLE?>` notation to add a variable to any non-php code.

```
?>    
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "trainerModulview.php?groupID="<?=$currentGroupID?>&lastDeletedUser=<?=$currentGroupID?>",
        success: function(data) {

        },
    });
</script>
<?php
```

Also, Javascript and Jquery notation uses '+' to add a JS variable into a JS string.

```
var variable=1;
var yourstring="this the #"+variable+" string";
```

While php uses '.'.

```
$variable=1;
$yourstring="this the #".$variable." string";
```

Also, if you are using double quotes, you can just do, but it's better if you still use '.'.

```
$yourstring="this the #$variable string";
```

But for single quotes you need to use '.'.

```
$yourstring='this the the #'.$variable.' string';
```

Also, you can do this to make more clean instead of echo:

```
<?php
$phpstring='this is php';
?>
<script>
 var jsstring='this is JS';
 var phpstring='<?=$phpstring?>';
 alert(phpstring);
</script>
<?php
echo $phpstring;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using + operator to concat string inside php. You need to USE . "Dot" operatore to cancat strings with variables.

```
echo '<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "trainerModulview.php?groupID="'.$currentGroupID.'"&lastDeletedUser="'.$id.'",
    success: function(data) {

    },
});
```

';